# How to open new form when click on button in CF7?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form, contact-form-7

I created a form using contact form 7. In that form two buttons are there. When you click on submit button it will execute the current created form. What I want is, when I click on another button, it should display another form take 2-3 fields with submit button.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what exatly you're trying to achieve.
do you want the second form to show on the same page, or you want it to be on another page (meaning a click on second button will redirect the user)?

If you want to redirect to another page with a new form, you can just use:

```
[submit "Submit this form"]

<button href="http://example.com/path_to_other_form">Open the other form</button>
```

Please note that generally including two buttons is a bad practice.
Why not using a normal link for the second form?...

Answer (score 0):

Contact Form 7 only supports a single Submit button ( as per standard HTML forms).

To add a second active button you would need to use custom Javascript.